# Python keyboard module error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-keyboard

My code is:

```
import keyboard

pressed = ""

def on_key_press():
    print("Key pressed.")
    global pressed
    # Took me 1 hour to figure out this.
    if charset.chars.__contains__(keyboard.read_key()):
        print("processing slangs...")
        print("*process*")
    else:
        print("registered key.")
        pressed += keyboard.read_key()
    print(pressed)

keyboard.on_press(on_key_press())
keyboard.wait()
```

I ran it as root.
When I press a key, it prints the key as intended.
But, when I press any key right after it, it just returns an error, like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keyboard/_generic.py", line 22, in invoke_handlers
    if handler(event):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 474, in <lambda>
    return hook(lambda e: e.event_type == KEY_UP or callback(e), suppress=suppress)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

and it keeps print out errors like that, don't matter what key I pressed.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*not reading the docs be like*
The function `keyboard.on_press()` invokes a **callback**, **not a function**.
This code shows that:

```
import keyboard

def test(a):
    print(a)

keyboard.on_press(test)
keyboard.wait()
```

When you press random keys, it prints out `KeyboardEvent(<key> down)`. The key string can be extracted using `keyboard.read_key()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only thing you need to remove the parenthesis when calling the `on_key_press` function

```py
keyboard.on_press(on_key_press())
```

to this one:

```py
keyboard.on_press(on_key_press)
```

my guess is that the method `keyboard.on_press` takes as an argument a function, not a callable object

Comment: Did you run the code ```TypeError: on_key_press() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given```